# GIt: How far back can you go in history after a commit?

Tags: git

Let's say I made a commit today, and tomorrow another Developer made a commit, something broke, how far in the commit history can we go back?

Comment: ? You can go back until the first commit. I think you have to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back to the initial uploaded virgin version.